# Play PowerPoint slide show with custom timings on TV

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, playback

I have a PowerPoint slideshow that uses custom transitions to advance the slides slides at different timings. I saved the slideshow to JPEG and transferred it to a memory stick to display on a TV. It plays but doesn't use the individual timings I set in PowerPoint. Instead, the TV gives me the option of fast, medium or slow transition.

How can I play my PowerPoint slideshow on a TV using my custom transition timings?

Comment: Once you save the slides to image files, you lose all of the Powerpoint functionality.  It sounds like you are using a slideshow function built into the TV.  Such internal functions aren't computer-related and are off-topic on Super User (product shopping recommendations are also off-topic).  If you want to control the action, you would likely need to use the TV as a monitor and use software on your computer to display what you want (which takes you back to Powerpoint).

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean when you say you saved them to jpeg? If the PowerPoint is not being viewed as the PowerPoint itself, but as a slideshow of pictures, then the timing won't be saved.

I would suggest exporting as a video. You can follow the advice [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-powerpoint/powerpoint-slideshow-be-viewed-in-a-lcdled-tv/0f246d35-0ecf-4267-a83d-7877f4145e0b).

> Go to **File** → **Export**
>
> You may now use one of the two options: **Create a Video** or **Package Presentation for CD**

Comment: Package Presentation for CD won't help, as OP mentioned that they want to play the result on a TV, not a computer.  Whether creating a video is available or not will depend on the PPT version, which OP didn't mention.